# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=2,address=0x8) thread cause while runtime

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

can any one help me in this error. i try lots but get same error each and every time.

```
NSMutableArray *temp_array;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 

//... other code
 NSArray *dataarray = [[[mydata objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"concept"] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    temp_array = [[dataarray mutableCopy] autorelease];
}


-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)design_no
{

    productLbl.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[temp_array objectAtIndex:[design_no intValue]]] autorelease];

    // I got error at this place like EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=2,address=0x8) thread cause while runtime.

}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender{

    CGFloat pageWidth = sender.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((sender.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    if (page==previousPage_) {
        return;
    }

    //incase we are still in same page, ignore the swipe action

    [self setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",page]];

}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollViewd;{
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollViewd.frame.size.width;
    previousPage_ = floor((scrollViewd.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

}
```

i just wont to change LABLE text when i scroll page in scrollview.

Comment: Where are you getting `productLbl` from? You should probably be using a property here so it should most likely be `self.productLbl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replace

```
temp_array = [[dataarray mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

to

```
temp_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: dataarray];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to viewDidLoad: `temp_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]` to initialise it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because, you autorelease your [dataarray mutableCopy]. Use it like this:

```
temp_array = [dataarray mutableCopy];
```